# Java: Call a main method from a main method in another class

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, java-8, program-entry-point

I have a set of Java files in the same package, each having main methods. I now want the main methods of each of the classes to be invoked from another class step by step. One such class file is Splitter.java. Here is its code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\en-sent.bin");
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\input.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(strLine);

    try {
        SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
        SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);
        String sentences[] = sentenceDetector.sentDetect(strLine);

        System.out.println(sentences.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(sentences[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (modelIn != null) {
            try {
                modelIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

I now want this to be invoked in `AllMethods.java` inside a main method. 
So how can I do this? There are several other class files having main methods with `IOException` which have to be invoked in `AllMethods.java` file.

Update -

I have main methods having `IOException` as well as main methods not having `IOEXception` that has to be invoked in `AllMethods.java`.

Comment: throwing an exception doesn't change much, you just have to add `throws IOException` to whatever method you're calling from (or catch/handle the exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you should probably do is refactor your code so each main method calls some other method, and then AllMethods makes calls to those new methods.  I can imagine there might be some cases where it's useful if you're just trying to, for example, write some test code, but usually you wouldn't want to call main methods directly.  It's just harder to read.

If you want to try it though, it's pretty easy, you just call the main method like any other static method.  I once in college wrote a web server where, to handle authentication, I recursed on the main method.  I think I got a C because it was unreadable code, but I had fun writing it.

```java
class AllMethods {
    public void callsMain() {
        String[] args = new String[0];
        Splitter.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that. Main method is also just like any other static method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 ....// do all the stuff


Splitter.main(args); // or null if no args you need
}
```

Comment: I have main methods having IOException and not having IOException. And I want all of them to be invoked in AllMethods.java. Can I use your suggestion for main methods NOT having IOException as well?

Comment: No. If the method method is throwing that exception it should caught by the caller. I mean you need to surround your call with `try-catch` and need to the necessary steps on failure.

Comment: Then how should I be calling all of those main methods in AllMethods.java?

Comment: @DakshilaKamalsooriya again, please read about `try-catch`. You'll understand

Answer (score -1):

In the Main.java, the main method should add throws Exception as shown below:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main extends makeFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        makeFile callMakeFile = new makeFile();

        makeFile.main(args);
        // cannot figure out how to call the main method from the makeFile class here...
    }
}
```